# Using timestamp for redux reducer keys

Tags: timestamp, react-native, redux, reducers

I'm considering using timestamps as keys for events using the following pattern in my React-Native reducer:

```
events: ["1458337324","1458399999","1458442999","1458443999"],
event_types: {
  "1458227324":"NET::connected",
  "1458442999":"ACT::pause",
  ...
```

is this an anti-pattern?

Second, I plan on using the timestamp to access other event objects as a foreign key relationship so I need the timestamp to be the same in each reducer. I can create and send the timestamp from each action but is there some easier way send a global timestamp through each reducer every time?

Comment: You might want to consider what happens on a key collision. In that case you will lose some data.